# Search text inside all files in all directories (and subdirectories) in project with SpaceVim

Tags: neovim, fzf, fuzzyfinder, spacevim

So I just started using Neovim/Spacevim, and it's so awesome!

I am still getting used to everything, since I have never used Vim or anything like that before.

My question revolves around searching for particular text in all the files of the currently open project.

I am using the `nerdtree` file manager, and I was wondering how I might search through all the files in the project for a specific string. Like if I wanted to search `function thisExactFunction()` throughout the currently open folder/directory, how would I go about doing that? The main goal is to have a list of all the files that contain this search string.

I have `fzf` installed (as well as `ripgrep`), but seem to be having trouble in searching for specific text inside of all files. I can only search for files themselves, or some other search that does not yield what I need.

Can anyone point me in the right direction...? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `Ggrep` command that Fzf supplies - see this [series of vim screencasts](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/03/combining-vimgrep-with-git-ls-files/) to see how to use vim's in built features (quickfix list populated by :vimgrep) to achieve the same using other grepping tools.

#### Custom functions

I have a function in my .vimrc that uses [ag silver
searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) to search within all
the files in a directory (and any subdirectories). So if you install ag, this
should work:

```
" Ag: Start ag in the specified directory e.g. :Ag ~/foo
function! s:ag_in(bang, ...)
    if !isdirectory(a:1)
        throw 'not a valid directory: ' .. a:1
    endif
    " Press `?' to enable preview window.
    call fzf#vim#ag(join(a:000[1:], ' '),
                \ fzf#vim#with_preview({'dir': a:1}, 'right:50%', '?'), a:bang)
endfunction

" Ag call a modified version of Ag where first arg is directory to search
command! -bang -nargs=+ -complete=dir Ag call s:ag_in(<bang>0, <f-args>)
```

#### Bonus

Sometimes it's hard to find things in vim's help, so I also have a function
that uses the one above to interactively search the help docs. This can be nice
to hone in on the topic you want. Use `:H` for this function (as opposed to the
classic `:h`)

```
function! Help_AG()
    let orig_file = expand(@%)
    let v1 = v:version[0]
    let v2 = v:version[2]
    " search in the help docs with ag-silver-search and fzf and open file
    execute "normal! :Ag /usr/share/vim/vim".v1.v2."/doc/\<CR>"
    " if we opened a help doc
    if orig_file != expand(@%)
        set nomodifiable
        " for some reason not all the tags work unless I open the 'real' help
        " so get whichever help was found and open it through Ag
        let help_doc=expand("%:t")
        " open and close that help doc - now the tags will work
        execute "normal! :tab :help " help_doc "\<CR>:q\<CR>"
    endif
endfunction

" get some help
command! H :call Help_AG()
```

Comment: Pretty freakin awesome! Good stuff, thanks alot!!

Comment: @Lushmoney Glad it helped you - I added a bonus function for searching the help pages in the same way using ag and fzf.

Comment: Oooh so awesome!! Thanks again, this is really great stuff.

Comment: @Lushmoney Ok [one more great screencast series](http://derekwyatt.org/vim/tutorials/) from which I learned a lot

Comment: You're the man, thank you so much!!